# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really really stuck and annoyed with this right now.

I am running Rails 2.3.5

My `View/pages/customers.html.erb` simply has:

```
<% form_tag do %>
    First Name
        <%= text_field_tag :firstName, params[:firstName] %>
    Last Name
        <%= text_field_tag :lastName, params[:lastName] %>

        <%= submit_tag "Enter" %>
<%end%>
```

My `Models/customer.rb` simply has:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :firstName, :lastName
end
```

My `Controller/pages_controller` has

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def custs
    @cust = Customer.new(params[:firstName], params[:lastName])
    @cust.save
  end
end
```

so as you see I am just trying to enter two fields from front end and then save them to the DB.  However, whenever i load my page it give me error:

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
>   pages_controller.rb:3:in `new'
>   pages_controller.rb:3:in`custs'

weird thing is that when I use the sandbox script/console I am able to insert data fine.

What is going on here? please someone explain!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class here is a little explanation of the new function. The crucial part - "pass a hash with key names matching the associated table column name". Instead of `@cust = Customer.new(params[:firstName], params[:lastName])` you should have `@cust = Customer.new(:firstName => params[:firstName], :lastName => params[:lastName])`. This should do the trick.

Comment: awesome answer. now I want my last hour back

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is to change line `3` of `pages_controller` to this:

```
@cust = Customer.new({:firstName => params[:firstName], :lastName => params[:lastName]})
```

Without proper `keys` Rails has no idea what values you are passing and in what order.

The bigger problem seems to be that your form is not setup properly. You might have a great reason for it, but if not, I would recommend creating a blank Rails project, and using `generate scaffold` to see how a normal Rails form/controller is setup.

Comment: yeah i was just playing around with it. and removed some stuff from the form to avoid verbosity.  I dont like scaffolding. I could not believe that AWDR book makes use of scaffolding all the way to chapter 6!

Answer (score 0):

Since `new` takes a hash, from which attributes will be set where the hash has the corresponding keys, `Customer.new(params)` should be sufficient, shouldn't it? Unless params also has keys for attributes that you don't want to be set in this case, I suppose.

Obviously your sample code may have been edited-down to better present the problem, but as shown, the `#new`/#`save` pair can usually be condensed down to `Customer#create(params)`